# How to get a session variable via javascript from an asp server script

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm new to the javascript world and have a simple test to read session vars in javascript:

my asp file:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Session("id")=1234
Session("code")="ZZ"
%>
```

my html file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="asp/testSession.asp">
    alert("Session ID " + Session("id"));
</script>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ASP code has to be placed between `<%` and `%>` tags to be processed server-side:

```
alert("Session ID " + <%=Session("id") %>);
                      ^^^ add tags     ^^
```

Also, you can use `<%=` as a shortcut to output a variable.  It's short for `Response.Write`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix javascript and asp in the way you did it. Javascript is executed locally while asp is compiled by the server and then send to your browser.

When the page reaches your browser, only the product of the asp compilation remains. In order to use the value or print it, you should do the following :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="asp/testSession.asp">
    alert("Session ID " + <%=Session("id")%>);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not always the case.  Classic ASP can process server side "JScript".  If you use a script tag with language "JScript" and runat="server", the script will be run server side and can interop with server-side VBScript code.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288965